# Is it possible to use a View and Activity together on a single page on android?

Tags: android

I have to design a page where, the top portion of the page should have buttons,textview etc.. and the the second portion of the page to have a View to make some animated ball moving around on button clicks of upper part..

Is it relative layout i should use ? or surface view ?

i am not sure how to proceed.. can someone help on this..?

Comment: Check out my answer. I hope it helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to define the layout with two child views, one which is a self-implemented `SurfaceView` class, the other is a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`, whichever suits your needs better. Check out this small example below on how to create a layout which has a `RelativeLayout` attached to the bottom and a `SurfaceView` on the top.

```
public void setupContentView() {
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    MySurfaceView mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    RelativeLayout xmlLayout = (Relativelayout) View.inflate(this, 
        R.layout.my_xml_file, null);

    int xmlId = 0x1234;
    xmlLayout.setId(xmlId);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams xmlParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    xmlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    xmlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    surfaceViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, xmlId);
    surfaceViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(xmlLayout, xmlParams);
    layout.addView(mySurfaceView, surfaceViewParams);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

This creates a layout inflated from an xml file called `my_xml_file` and names is `xmlLayout`. It also creates a self-implemented `SurfaceView` class called `MySurfaceView` which it calls `mySurfaceView`. Then, it sets the paramaters using the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` class to both layouts. It sets the `mySurfaceView` below the `xmlLayout` and both heights are set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, which would make the `mySurfaceView` take up the entire screen if the xml height = 0 and vise versa. You would then draw however you would in the `MySurfaceView` class however you would normally, and the xml file can be set up however you'd like.
Best of luck! Would love to hear back on any success.

Comment: Adam, I tried all the possible ways t get it, but no luck.. the surface view is taking whole page, i want only half of the page to be canvas and another half to be XML layout with buttons..

Comment: @ramakrishna Even after loading an XML file int `xmlLayout`, your `SurfaceView` still took up the entire screen?